# Merge import-csv result to variable - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am very new to powershell. My question is how can I read a column from a .csv and leave that data in a comma separated variable?
csv example:

```
1
2
3
4
```

What I need is to leave it this way, in a variable:

`$store`
`1,2,3,4`

I'm using the import-csv cmdlet and tried join but it doesn't work:

`$csv = Import-Csv -Path "c:\temp\FileName.csv" -Header "store" $csv $csv -join ','`

I went through many answers from this site but i couldn't assimilate any for my case.

Thanks!

Comment: `Import-Csv` parses your Csv into objects. If you want to get the Csv as plain text then use `Get-Content`

Comment: Also note that @(1, 2,  3, 4)  is an array of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following to create an array with the information you want.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\FileName.csv" -Header "store" 
$myarray = $csv.store
$myarray | get-member
'   '
$myarray[0]
$myarray[1]
$myarray[2]
$myarray[3]
```

Notes:

Your csv contains only one field, and no commas.
Once you import it,  the imported data is an array of PSCustomobject.
Accessing the only field by name yields an array of strings.
The get-member shows you the features of the underlying strings.
The access to the components by index show the contents of the components.
Note that it start with zero.

An array of strings may be what you really want.  If so,  thisa example should help.

Comment: Thanks for reply. One question: if the field is variable I need replicate the $myarray[x]  for each line in the csv?  I’ve tried the others answers and when the csv have one line don’t work.

Comment: I intended the indexed reference only for purposes of illistration.  There a pots of other ways of referencing an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $csv=import-csv -LiteralPath "c:\temp\FileName.csv"
    $csv.column1 -join ','
```

Please replace Column1 in $csv.column1, with your actual column name in the csv file